# How can I set the callback event for the popup window?

Tags: acumatica

I appreciate if you could give me a help that how to set the callback event for the pop-up window, the circumstance is:

I do not want users can create APInvoice directly in my case, so I created the "Document Entry" custom page to let user input invoice data in it temporary. Then, the administrators approve and click the "Create New Bill" button to pop-up the "New Bill" window filled with the data from the parent Document. After the administrator has completed the Bill, he clicks the "Save & Close" button then the pop-up page is closed and the event in the parent page is triggered. My description is complicated but the logic is clear and simple as the following graphic, can you please tell how I can set the callback event? Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorate your action button event handler PXButton attribute with OnClosingPopup property:

```
[PXButton(OnClosingPopup = PXSpecialButtonType.Cancel)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "View Document Graph")]
public virtual IEnumerable ViewDocumentGraph(PXAdapter adapter)
{
}
```

You can use either:

```
PXSpecialButtonType.Cancel
```

Or:

```
PXSpecialButtonType.Refresh
```

Cancel will invalidate the document then fetch and re-bind it. It's a good choice when the popup modifies the parent window document. It's equivalent to pressing the cancel button.

Note that this functionality is better supported on Chrome navigator, I noticed some glitch using Edge.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no direct callback so I would suggest having the popup window modify the parent window data even if it's not necessary. Using OnClosingPopup you force the DAC record to refresh so you can detect changes of the DAC field.

Comment: In your specific case, you could add a custom field in the parent window DAC record to hold the APInvoice ID. When you open the child APInvoiceEntry window you can pass the parent DAC record to the APInvoiceEntry graph. Create a APInvoiceEntry graph extension  and use RowPersisted event to set APInvoice ID of the parent window DAC record.

Comment: Hi @HB_ACUMATICA, yes, I have passed the Document ID to the new APInvoice when opening the popup page, thanks a lot for your suggestion and will tag your answer is right after having tested it.